# How to make a side menu sublist horizontali in my code

Tags: html

I have an html code. I want to create a horizontal sublist in my code. The movies link needs some sublist like upcoming movie,new releases and past movies.

Here is my code:

Menu

```
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Equipments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Thanks...

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Css With Html like this

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal

```
 <style>
  ul
  {
  list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }
 li
 {
 display:inline;
 }
 </style>

 <ul>
   <li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Equipments</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Please provide a snippet, or more information on how to do it. A good answer should be more than a link.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `CSS` to help you create horizontal menus, the instructions should be something like this :

```
.menu ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.munu li{
  display: inline;
}
```

In your html, you just need to add the `menu` class, which is just created, to the `<div>` tag :

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Equipments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note: DONT forget to include your css file into html, if you use an external css file,  by using the following instruction :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```